# Laravel5.3 session not working in controllers class

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

i am using laravel 5.3

Session not storing in controllers class method 
I think the problem is with connect to api. after connect to api session not work

`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\GlosbeTranslate as Translate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class translateLocal extends Controller
{
     public $arrayDefine;  
     public function translate($word){
            //connect to glosbe Api to translate from eng to fas 
            $glosbe = new Translate("eng", "fas");
            $glosb=$glosbe->translate($word);
            $result=json_decode($glosb);
            //store result of glosbe api in array 
            foreach ($result->tuc as $key=>$value){
                if(isset($value->phrase)){
                    $translate[]=$value->phrase->text;
                }else{break;};
            }
            $sortedArray=$this->sort($translate);
            $encodearray=json_encode($sortedArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            //save in session
            session(['name' => $encodearray]);
            return $encodearray;
        }

        public function sort($translate){
           usort($translate,function ($a,$b){
                return strlen($a)-strlen($b);
            });
            return $translate;
        }
}
```

// my web.php

```
Route::get('glosb/{word}', 'translateLocal@translate');
Route::get('/session', function () {     
        echo session('name');
});
```

when i load mysite.dev/session it's not show my session.
how can i solve that?

Comment: What you mean `it does not show my session`? its blank page or you have an error message?

Comment: Route::post('/vocabulary', 'vocabulary@set') ? That is pointing to wrong place if that is what you are hitting.

Comment: @Paul thank for reply i edit my question.

Comment: @MoeinPorkamel when i load mysite.dev/session . it return blank page.

Comment: Try this to see if session is empty or something else is wrong: ```Route::get('/session', function () {     
        echo session('name', 'SESSION EMPTY');
});```

Comment: @MoeinPorkamel it's show 'session empty'

Comment: @MohammadChavoshi so your `translate` method is doing something wrong and its not laravel related.

Comment: translate method return true and work properly but not store session

Answer (score 0):

Can you give it a try?

Change

`use App\putSession;`

to

`use Session;`

Comment: thank you for reply: no it's not work. i have used facade, helper function and direct instantiate session class. but now working

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code like:

```
use Session;

session(['name' => $encodearray]);
```

TO

```
Session::put('name',$encodearray]);
```

and change your route `/session` like:

```
Route::get('/session', function () {
    $name = Session::get('name');    
       echo $name;

   OR

   echo session('name');
});
```

Comment: not it's not working . i am wounder why . i don't have problem with other controllers .